# Swift Timing of PopUp and Dispatch Async

Tags: swift, popup, dispatch-async

I'm a beginner swiftprogrammer who is experiencing problems with the timing of function calls. I would like an explanation of why this happens and a way to fix it. The problem arise in a code segment that runs when one pop up closes and I want to first open another popup and then after a button has been pressed in the new pop up I want the program to do something additionally in the main view controller. Here is the code (someone suggested using DispatchQue but it doesn't seem to do anything):

```
@objc func onPopupClosed() {
print("first")

DispatchQueue.main.async {
 if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController (withIdentifier: 
    "P2CompetitionPopUpId") as? P2_Competition_Pop_Up 
            {
                vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                print("error creating P2_Competion_Pop_Up")
            }
        }
print ("third")     
}
```

And P2_Competition_Pop_Up looks as follows:

```
class P2_Competition_Pop_Up: UIViewController {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //print("Second")
 }

@IBAction func Slot1(_ sender: Any) {

    //some code

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
}
```

I want this program to result in the output "first" "second" "third" (and to print "third" only after the button has been pressed in the popup.). Instead it gives me "first" "third" "second". Why? And how do I fix it? Is using DispatchQue the right way to go or is there another one?

ps. the "print ("third")" statement is really a modification of how the main view look. I just used this statement to highlight the order difficulty and to simplify the illustration.

Answer (score 0):

There is no gurantee that in your code "Second" or "Third" will print first.
But if you want something done after you presented a `UIViewController`, you should do it in the `present` completion block.

```
    if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController (withIdentifier: "P2CompetitionPopUpId") as? P2_Competition_Pop_Up {
      vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
      self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: {
          // do it here
          print ("third")     
      })
    } else {
      print("error creating P2_Competion_Pop_Up")
    }
```

Also you can write in sugar syntax

```
      self.present(vc, animated: true) {
          print ("third")     
      }
```

Comment: This does not print "third" only after the button has been pressed in the popup as requested. It prints third once the pop up has finished loading.

Comment: then you should put the print third in `func Slot1`

Comment: It needs to run in the main view. See the ps.